# Rewrite DataGrid-GroupStyle XAML into C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, groupstyle

Can someone please rewrite this XAML into C# code ?

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
 </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

I tried this but it did not work:

```
// Setup Grouping
            GroupStyle groupStyle = new GroupStyle();
            groupStyle.ContainerStyle.Resources.FindName("GroupHeaderStyle");
            groupStyle.Panel = new DataGridRowsPresenter();
```

Can`t get the last Line working...

UPDATE:

```
 // Setup Grouping
            GroupStyle groupStyle = new GroupStyle();  
            groupStyle.ContainerStyle.Resources.FindName("GroupHeaderStyle");
            groupStyle.Panel = new ItemsPanelTemplate(new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DataGridRowsPresenter)));
```

Comment: Saw that you updated your question while I was answering, you got it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it :)

```
FrameworkElementFactory datagridRowsPresenter = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DataGridRowsPresenter));
ItemsPanelTemplate itemsPanelTemplate = new ItemsPanelTemplate();
itemsPanelTemplate.VisualTree = datagridRowsPresenter;
GroupStyle groupStyle = new GroupStyle();
groupStyle.Panel = itemsPanelTemplate;
dataGrid.GroupStyle.Add(groupStyle);

Uri resourceLocater = new Uri("/YourAssemblyName;component/SubDirectory/YourFile.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocater);
groupStyle.ContainerStyle = resourceDictionary["GroupHeaderStyle"] as Style;
```

Comment: your code is fine BUT my Resource "GroupHeaderStyle" is defined in another XAML file. The code you gave me is inside a .cs custom control file. How would you access the ressource... ok I make an extra question of it thats better...

Comment: Updated my answer, something similar to this depending on assembly and directory

Answer (score 0):

This link must be helpful: http://www.netframeworkdev.com/windows-presentation-foundation-wpf/setting-an-itemscontrolpanels-content-from-code-86898.shtml

BTW, you perhaps want

```
groupStyle.ContainerStyle = Resources.FindName("GroupHeaderStyle");
```

instead of

```
groupStyle.ContainerStyle.Resources.FindName("GroupHeaderStyle");
```

Edit:
in order to get the container correct, you need to get it from the resources. These are either Window resources, or the application-wide resources. I guess `Application.Current.Resources.FindName("GroupHeaderStyle");` should find the correct resources, unless you are doing something special.

Comment: updated my question with new code: How can I create a ContainerStyle because its NULL ? funny I can create a Style and assign it to ContainerStyle I thought it takes ContainerSTyle instances only...